# How to optimise this aggregation using Array.reduce

Tags: javascript

I have attached a working snippet ,I am looking for more optimised solution ,as I will be dealing with fairly large amount of  data .Any solution  with  fairly less complexity and more optimised  which you can suggest thanks.

```js
let data = [

  {
    category_name: "Home",
    isparent: true
  },
  {
    category_name: "City",
    isparent: true
  },
  {
    category_name: "Home town",
    parent: "Home",
    isparent: false
  },
  {
    category_name: "City_town",
    parent: "City",
    isparent: false
  }
]

/**
 * req 
 * let data=[
 * {category_name:"home",
 *  children:[{""}]
 * }
 * ]
 */


let res = data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  let obj = {
    children: []

  }
  if (ele.isparent) {
    obj = ele;
    obj.children = [];
    acc.push(obj);

  } else {
    let _filt = acc.find(_ele => _ele.category_name == ele.parent)
    _filt.children.push(ele);
  }

  return acc;


}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: _"Please suggest any library..."_ -> off-topic

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: What is your desired data structure?  That might help a bit.

Comment: Try databases like MongoDB for large amout of data

Comment: Which is coming in the result in snippet @dmitrydwhite

Comment: Are category names guaranteed to be unique? Also, is a category guaranteed to appear before any of its children?

Comment: Yes they are unique @Klaycon

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is inefficient because of the nested `acc.find()` - it will cause the solution to approach `O(N^2)`. You can achieve a much more efficient solution as you have unique keys, just make a map/dictionary (native js object works fine for this) - I think it is a much easier format to work with but you can simply `Object.values(map)` to get the requested output format.

```js
let data = [ { category_name: "Home", isparent: true }, { category_name: "City", isparent: true }, { category_name: "Home town", parent: "Home", isparent: false }, { category_name: "City_town", parent: "City", isparent: false } ];

let res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  if (ele.isparent) {
    acc[ele.category_name] = ele;
    ele.children = [];
  } else {
    acc[ele.parent].children.push(ele);
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

This implementation only requires one loop over the data and is closer to `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?  Not sure if it's more performant, but maybe a little?

```js
const as_obj = data.reduce((accum, curr) => {
  const { category_name, isparent, parent } = curr;

  if (isparent && accum[category_name]) {
    // This is a parent, but we've already seen one of its children;
    // we created the parent key for that already.
    return accum;
  }

  if (isparent && !accum[category_name]) {
    // This is the first time we've seen the parent key, creating an object for it.
    return { ...accum, [category_name]: { ...curr, children: [] } };
  }

  if (parent && !accum[parent]) {
    // We haven't seen this child's parent yet, but we'll make a place for it.
    accum[parent] = { category_name, children: [] };
  }

  const children = [ ...accum[parent].children, curr];

  return { ...accum, [parent]: { ...accum.parent, children } };

}, {});

const res = Object.values(as_obj);
```

Comment: When thinking of performance, avoid spread operators like the plague. Each use of spread operator requires the entire object/array to be iterated over an additional time, it is unnecessary when e.g. `accum[category_name] = curr;` or `accum[parent].children.push(curr)` are way shorter, faster, and more readable.

Comment: Also this code will error on the objects that don't have a `parent` property due to the destructuring assignment at the top

Comment: I don't think so; so long as `curr` is an object, it can be destructured.  If it doesn't have a `parent` property, then the variable `parent` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Hm, you're correct, my mistake. I remember running into a similar issue a while back, I must have misunderstood the cause at the time.